# OxyPlot dll error - Strongly Named Assembly required

Tags: .net, wpf, oxyplot

I am a UI developer trying to research OxyPlot for potential use in a project. I have installed the NuGet packages but when I try to place an instance on an OxyPlot control on my window I get a build error stating that I need a "strongly-named assembly. If i remove the OxyPlot instance then my project builds. Anyone have any knowledge on this?

Comment: Can you post more information! Code? XAML?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have it working now, not actually sure what the issue was. Many thanks